# dynamically types and views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a several events: films, performance, sports events and other. Initialy I want to create base class(Event) and  separate class for event type: Film class, Sport class ....
But, many class is empty, because they don't have specific fields. Therefore, I decided create one class `Event` and separate class `EventType`. And create all fields for all all events in one class:

```
public class Event
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string Duration { get; set; }
   public string DirectorList { get; set; }
   public string ActorList { get; set; }
   public string Genre { get; set; }

   public EventType Type {get; set;}
   ...
}

public class EventType
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

But some types of events may not have some fields. For example, sport events don't have `ActorList` or `DirectorList`. I decided in the action of controller determine the type of event and show the appropriate view. And suppose we have seven event types and seven views. In CMS the user want to add new event type, but the view for this event type not created by me.

How to allow the user to create new event types and generate views for this type?

PS. What you think about design of my database?
Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: Why do you have DirectorList and ActorList in your base Event type?

Comment: Because I put all fields in one class `Event`. In this way I don't have to create other class(Film, Sport...)

Comment: What's wrong with that? that's exactly how it should be done in OOP

Comment: There is `EventType` property. In this property will saved event type. As I said, the user may create new event type in CMS. But view for this type not create by me.

Comment: If users can define new event types would that also entail the need to define new properties?

Answer (score 0):

You should use inheritance here defining a Event class with only the base properties:

```
public class Event
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then create another class:

```
public class FilmEvent : Event
{
   public string ActorList { get; set; }
   public string DirectorList { get; set; }
}
```

Type can be inferred from the class itself now.

Comment: Initially I used this way. But then I get empty classes. For example, Sport. It's don't have specific fileds and it will be empty.

Comment: How is that a problem? It just makes your Sports class extendable in the future.

Comment: This way not flexible. For example, customer want add new event type. In this case I must to create new class and view, then deploy on server. New way (without separate class) allow the customer create new event type without me.